# 'm trying to return the value of the variables in this contract but I get the error:"Uncaught TypeError: web3.eth.watch is not a function"

Tags: web3js

```
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
      web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
  }

  web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];

  var mediachainContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_instagramPassword","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"setSocialMedia3","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"userCount","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_linkedinPassword","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"setSocialMedia2","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newFileContent","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"setFile","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"user","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getAccounts","outputs":[{"name":"facebookPassword","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"linkedinPassword","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"instagramPassoword","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"fileContent","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_facebookPassword","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"setSocialMedia","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"}]);

  var mediachain = mediachainContract.at('0x5d8e0ed3e15468c94fe17fbd215756a78d40e857');
  console.log(mediachain);
  var badPassword = $("#Name").val();
  $("#set1").click(function() {
    mediachain.setSocialMedia($("#Facebookpasswd").val());
    var safePassword = $("#Facebookpasswd").val();
    if (safePassword.length <= 10) {
      alert("Password doesn't meet minimum requirements");
    }
    var goodPassword = [safePassword];
    if (goodPassword.includes("1234567890") == true) {
      alert("Password doesn't meet minimum requirements");
    }
    if (goodPassword.includes("abcdefghij") == true) {
      alert("Password doesn't meet minimum requirements");
    }
    if (goodPassword.includes("ABCDEFGHIJ") == true) {
      alert("Password doesn't meet minimum requirements");
    }
    if (goodPassword.includes("Password") == true) {
      alert("Password doesn't meet minimum requirements");
    }
    if (goodPassword.includes(badPassword) == true) {
      alert("Password doesn't meet minimum requirements");
    }
  });
  $("#set2").click(function() {
    mediachain.setSocialMedia2($("#Linkedinpasswd").val());
    var safePassword2 = $("#Linkedinpasswd").val();
    if (safePassword2.length <= 10) {
      alert("Password doesn't meet minimum requirements");
    }
    var goodPassword2 = [safePassword2];
    if (goodPassword2.includes("1234567890") == true) {
      alert("Password doesn't meet minimum requirements");
    }
    if (goodPassword2.includes("abcdefghij") == true) {
      alert("Password doesn't meet minimum requirements");
    }
    if (goodPassword2.includes("ABCDEFGHIJ") == true) {
      alert("Password doesn't meet minimum requirements");
    }
    if (goodPassword2.includes("Password") == true) {
      alert("Password doesn't meet minimum requirements");
    }
    if (goodPassword2.includes(badPassword) == true) {
      alert("Password doesn't meet minimum requirements");
    }
  });
  $("#set3").click(function() {
    mediachain.setSocialMedia3($("#Instagrampasswd").val());
    var safePassword3 = $("#Instagrampasswd").val();
    if (safePassword3.length <= 10) {
      alert("Password doesn't meet minimum requirements");
    }
    var goodPassword3 = [safePassword3];
    if (goodPassword3.includes("1234567890") == true) {
      alert("Password doesn't meet minimum requirements");
    }
    if (goodPassword3.includes("abcdefghij") == true) {
      alert("Password doesn't meet minimum requirements");
    }
    if (goodPassword3.includes("ABCDEFGHIJ") == true) {
      alert("Password doesn't meet minimum requirements");
    }
    if (goodPassword3.includes("Password") == true) {
      alert("Password doesn't meet minimum requirements");
    }
    if (goodPassword3.includes(badPassword) == true) {
      alert("Password doesn't meet minimum requirements");
    }
  });
  $("#newFile").change(function(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0]
    reader = new window.FileReader()
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
  });
  $("#setSomething").click(function() {
    mediachain.setFile($("#newFile").val());
  });
  web3.eth.watch('mediachain').changed(function() {
    var contractString = JSON.stringify(web3.eth.storageAt('0x4da9f2ef21cc01ea417477f4be070335a3658cb6'));
    document.getElementById("#showContract").innerText = contractString;
  });
```

Comment: The error message is correct. Can you point to where you saw `web3.eth.watch` documented?

Comment: https://dappsforbeginners.wordpress.com/tutorials/javascript-api-1/

Comment: Strange. As far as I can tell, neither web3.js 0.2x.x nor web3.js 1.0.0-beta include such a function. If you have a way to contact the author, I'd suggest directing your question to them.